# Computations after aggregate function

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, aggregate

I'd like to compute a measure with the data I have.

So, I began first by computing the average profit per individual with this function:
aggregate(profit ~ subjectid, AER, mean)

What I want to obtain is a mean of an individual measure. It means that for every individual I would like to have the mean of the average profit per subject.

Here I tried something which gives me the mean of the profit by subject but doesn't fit exactly my needs.

```
aggregate(profit ~ subjectid, AER, mean)
```

Since I have 936 individuals in my dataset, I obtain 936 lines of output (one average profit for every subject). Then, I'd like to subtract a number from this (let's say arbitrary 4) for every line. And then compute the whole mean of this for all my dataset.

```
aggregate(profit ~ subjectid, AER, mean)

subjectid      profit
1           1  3.2
2           2  0.3
3           3  2.2
4           4  3.0
5           5  3.0
6           6  1.2
...         ...
```

For instance, the calculation for these 6 lines would be :

```
mean((3.2-4)+(0.3-4)+(2.2-4)+(3-4)+(3-4)+(1.2-4))
```

So, the expected output at the end is just a number.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output as we don't know how it doesn't fit to your needs.  BTW, if you are using a formula, `aggregate(profit ~ subjectid, AER, mean)` is enough

Comment: Using dplyr: result <- AER %>% group_by(subjectid) %>% summarise(measure = mean(profit))... It's hard without examples...

Comment: Maybe it is now more clear for you to understand

Answer (score 1):

`aggregate` is the appropriate function. From the `mtcars` data, if you wanted to take the mean miles per gallon by number of cylinders (as a proxy for individuals in your dataset), you could use this. See `?mtcars` for a description of this dataset; it is useful for providing reproducible examples.

```
    aggregate(mpg ~ cyl, data=mtcars, FUN=mean)
```